# Control's of the Ribbon freeze

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm a newbie in sharepoint development! my problem is that a few day's I install SPF 2010 on Windows 2008 R2 SP1 and also install VS 2013 SP1 everything work fine at the first but today I try to change some config's of Sharepoint WebApplication (Default Web Application with port 80) I push the buttons of Manage web applications in Central Administrator but not firing so all of the control in Ribbon Freeze!!?

Look at this picture:

[image: look this picture]

this is my console errors:

[image]

I'm try to clicking on "SharePoint 80"

and this is my Event Viewer log:

[image]

Comment: Could you check your JavaScript console at the time that you click it? Any JavaScript errors being displayed?

Comment: Any suggestion? I reinstall SharePoint Foundation again but the problem not solve.

Comment: Oh shit!!! this is a crazy problem. the cause of problem was OS incorrect time :v.

Answer (score 1):

You must reset your sharepoint IIS Then open central admin with Run As Admin privilage.

Comment: No, unfortunately not work. this problem course after SP1 of VS 2013 install.